# Changing cursor when hovering a text

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to change the cursor to the pointer when hovering "text", since it links to a pop-up and not to a link, and i want to "hide" it between links. Is there a way?

```
<a onclick="myFunction()">Text</a>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("pop-up text");
}
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set a css rule:

HTML :

```
<a class=someRelevantClass onclick="myFunction()">Text</a>
```

CSS :

```
a.someRelevantClass {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

See [the available cursors in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Values).

Answer (score 1):

With CSS:

```
a{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you want it not to be a pointer on specific items you can use a `:not` pseudo-class to match anchors with `class="not-a-link"`:

```
a:not(.not-a-link){
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: The :hover makes no sense